# Get placeholder within gsub from array to print

Tags: ruby, regex, placeholder

This is my Code:

```
  str = "\\c 2 foo \\v 1 bar \\v 2 foo \\v 3 bar " +
  "\\v 4 foo \\c 3 bar \\v 1 foo \\v 2 bar"

  str.gsub!(/(\\c \d+)/, 'CHAPTER SPLIT \1')
  #=> CHAPTER SPLIT \c 2 foo \v 1 bar \v 2 foo \v 3 bar \v 4 foo CHAPTER SPLIT \c 3 bar \v 1 foo \v 2 bar

  str.split('CHAPTER SPLIT').map do |s|    
    s.scan(/\\c (\d+)/).each {|c| puts s.gsub!(/\\v (\d+)/, c.to_s + ':\1')}
  end

#=>  \c 2 foo ["2"]:1 bar ["2"]:2 foo ["2"]:3 bar ["2"]:4 foo 
#    \c 3 bar ["3"]:1 foo ["3"]:2 bar
```

The end result i'm looking for is

```
\c 2 foo 2:1 bar 2:2 foo 2:3 bar 2:4 foo 
\c 3 bar 3:1 foo 3:2 bar
```

There must be an easier way to do this than what I've done, I'm not sure how to get from the results I've got now to what It needs to be.

Comment: Can you format your code? I'm not getting what you meant..

Comment: I'm not sure you actually want gsub at all here, although you may want a regex to pull out parts, I'm not sure gsub is the right tool. Can you explain more clearly and completely what you want in terms of input and output, I don't understand what the `2:1` parts of your output are about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without reexp:

```
str = "\\c 2 foo \\v 1 bar \\v 2 foo \\v 3 bar " +
  "\\v 4 foo \\c 3 bar \\v 1 foo \\v 2 bar"

x = str.split.slice_before('\c').map do |c_token,chapter,*rest|
  [c_token,chapter]+rest.map.with_index do |x,ix|
    if rest[ix-1] == '\v'
        chapter+':'+x
    else 
        x
    end
  end
end

p x.flatten.join(' ')
```